# What is the 'kwframeid' attribute in an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

I've been seeing this attribute all over the internets and can't seem to find any answers as to what it is.  Eg:

```
<iframe src="https://yyy.zzz.com" kwframeid="2"></iframe>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

It's an attribute added from the dashlane plugin.

Answer (score -3):

The following is from CodePen:

```
<iframe id="result2560a92f992c8ac7816d9c931ce1111f1458766361028" 
    src="http://s.codepen.io/boomerang/2560a92f992c8ac7816d9c931ce1111f1458766361028/index.html?editors=1010"
    sandbox="allow-scripts allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-modals allow-forms"
    allowtransparency="true" class="result-iframe" kwframeid="2">
</iframe>
```

Comment: This answer does not explain what it's for